# Can't reach index.php in /en/ subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was asked to continue developing a website that was left behind.

Runs on a simple custom PHP backend CMS where you can add products, pages, change logo and other few basic operations.

Database: MySQL

Both frontend and backend works.

The website supposed to be multilanguage (it, en).
This is my folder structure:

```
--root
  --admin (backend CMS)
  --css
  --en
      --index.php (EN second language)
  --images
  --includes
  --js
index.php (IT main language)
products-category.php
.htaccess
```

This is my **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

I can reach both **index.php** (Main language) and admin CMS but when I go to **/en/index.php** redirects you to the **products-category.php** (Main language)

Who can help me understand what I'm missing?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is my `/en/index.php`

```php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['lang']='en';
require_once("../admin/config.php");
require_once("../include/function.php");
$page='home';
$language_file='';
$pop_up_modal_newsletter='no';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
** WEBSITE HTML **
```

**EDIT 2**

I copied the entire site and database on a XAMPP environment and everything works great, I can access every page inside the subfolder /en/

So I think it's a server issue, right?

Comment: Are you putting this in to the address bar or is this a `header()` that is the problem?

Comment: It may be possible that you have some wired RewriteRules in your .htaccess or the server configuration prevents this.

Comment: @Marco OP says their `.htaccess` file has `RewriteEngine Off`

Comment: If you only recently made changes in the .htaccess considering the rewriting - then go check this in a private browser window, to make sure this is not just a cached redirect fooling you. If that’s not it, then start by checking what the `/en/index.php` actually contains, maybe it is that script file itself that issues the redirect header.

Comment: In my `/en/index.php` I have this:
`<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['lang']='en';
require_once("../amministra/config.php");
require_once("../include/function.php");
$page='home';
$language_file='';
$pop_up_modal_newsletter='no';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 ** WEBSITE HTML **`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I'm putting in to the address bar

Comment: I edited my question, copying the entire site and database in XAMPP worked. It's a server issue then? Thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly: If it works on an other server the configuration should be the problem. The best is to check both configurations und match tham against each other.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured it out.
I placed an .htaccess file inside my /en/ subfolder with `DirectoryIndex index.php`. Works perfectly.